# gap between navbar and index, won't seem to go away with given suggestions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

There seems to be a gap between the navbar and the rest of the page. I am trying to get rid of that but to no avail. have tried adjusting margins etc. It keeps asking me to give more details befor posting this question and I don't really know how to give more detail than I already have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Josh Adams</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-    turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track':     'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Josh Adams</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Links</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  <div class="index" id="index-page">
    <div class="headline">About me</div>
    <hr>

    <div class="media col-8 offset-2">
      <span class="media-left">
        <%= image_tag("profilephoto.jpg") %>
      </span>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="media-heading">Joshua Adams:</h2>
        <h3 class=about-body>

        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>

@import "bootstrap";

#index-page {
  background: image_url('indexbackground.jpg');
  margin-top: 0px;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
}

.media {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.headline {
  font-size: 80pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'chunkfiveroman';
}

hr {
  width: 75%; 
  color: black; 
  height: 2px; 
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.media-heading {
  margin-left: 25px;
  color: white;

}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#index-page {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.index {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: By more details, it means a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can help you easier. You mentioned you've adjusted margins etc., is the margin on your headline still supposed to be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in your `.headline` class: `margin-top: 50px;` Remove that and it should look fine

Comment: thank you, I ended up getting it down. Not used to web design coding